# Terraform - response_parameters: should be a map

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, terraform, terraform-template-file

I have a terraform script for `api_gateway` which is working fine. I have a lot of templates duplicated. I want to extract all the templates using `"data" "template_file"`.

Working solution:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "ApiResponse" {
   //something goes here
     response_parameters  = {
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "'GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS'"
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "'*'"
      }
}
```

After refactoring:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "ApiResponse" {
   //something goes here
     response_parameters = "${data.template_file.response_parameters.template}"
}

data "template_file" "response_parameters" {
   template = "${file("${path.module}/response_parameters.tptl")}"
}
```

response_parameters.tptl:

```
{
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "'GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS'"
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "'*'"
}
```

Error:

```
* aws_api_gateway_integration_response.ApiResponse: response_parameters: should be a map
```

Since the response parameters are common for all my `aws_api_gateway_integration_response`, i want to have a common template and reuse in all resources.

Why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working with a `variable` of type `map` instead of `"data" "template_file"`

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "ApiResponse" {
//something goes here 
   response_parameters = "${var.integration_response_parameters}"
}

variable "integration_response_parameters" {
   type = "map"
   default = {
        method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers = "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
        method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods = "'GET,OPTIONS'"
        method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "'*'"
     }
}
```